# What are the different colloquial terms for Chinese mafia positions?

Tags: translation

I am creating a Chinese game where you are working with the Triads. I am looking for a list of Chinese equivalent names for the 黑社会 (triads).

Like (source: http://mafia.wikia.com/wiki/Ranks,_Titles_and_Positions_In_The_Mafia)

- Boss
- Consigliere
- Soldier

Etc...

I found this article: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triad_(underground_society)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triad_%28underground_society%29)

But I want to keep the names as colloquial as possible... such that I can reference someone who is superior to someone else

Like, one dialog section would be:

```
"Go talk to 李大哥, tell him I sent you."
```

**Some more context:**

So let's say my game is already in the context of the triads. And, everyone in the community is affiliated with the triads. And let's say a pawn is asked to go talk to someone, sent by one of the senior triad members. How can I reference that senior member?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A problem I think you're going to run into: mafia groups usually have their own terminology that *normal* people don't know - and normally wouldn't be used outside of the group.

Anyhow I found this on Wikipedia:

### **Triad structure**

[image: wiki]

and I found this comment online that should help you out a lot - I'm assuming your Chinese is good enough to understand:

> 香港三合会部有一定的组织结构和清代三合会的内八堂和外八堂类似。传统的组织结构可分为四个职级八个职位：（1）第一职级是山主（大路元帅），其数字代码为“489”。这三个数字之和为对，暗喻“洪”字，洪为“三八甘一”，其手势为左手的拇指、中指、尾指出，掌心向身。（2）第二职级为副山主（二路元帅）。该职级还包括先锋、香主等职位。其数字代码为“438”，这三个数字之和为15，暗喻纪念三合会前、中、后五祖。其手势为左手拇指和尾指伸直，掌心向身。（3）第三职级包括白纸扇、红根和草鞋三个职位。白纸扇一般充当军师之职。其数字代码是“415”，源于“4
>   x 15＋4”，合八卦之数，暗喻足智多谋。其手势是屈左手食指，其余指伸直，掌心向身。红棍负责执行“家法”，其数字代码是“426”，源于“4
>   x 26＋4”，合108之数，暗喻梁山泊好汉。其手势是拇指、食指和中指伸直，掌心向身。“草鞋”负责联络事宜，数字代码为“432”，源于“4
>   x
>   12＋4”，合132之数。暗喻西鲁故事少林寺替清朝打西域的寺僧。第四职级是普通会员，包括正式入会的四九仔和尚未参加入伙仪式的蓝灯笼。现时的三合会组织结构略有变化，出现了增数和坐馆之名号，“先锋”和“香主”之名号则很少使用。一般来讲，现时三合会组织大多实行“坐馆制”，坐馆表面上是中层领导，但由于是行动层和执行层的头目，总理帮中一切口激性事务，掌握着帮中的实际权力。坐馆之职一般必须具有“红根”资格才能担任。擅数是协调坐馆管理帮中财务等重大事宜的主要头目，一般多由具有白纸扇资格的职员充当。
>   　　香港三合会组织内部流传着三合会诗句和暗语等，一般现时很少使用，三合会诗句包括风诗、流诗、宝诗、印诗和表露所属之三合会堂的招牌诗。香港黑社会的暗语主要是从内地三合会沿袭下来，经过一百多年的演变，这些暗语经过香港三合会的修改，再加上广州话、潮州话等的音韵，已形成具有香港特色的黑帮语言。各个黑社会组织都有自己的暗语。例如老歪指和字系，尖顶指全字系，无下巴指同字系，条四指14K等。暗语使用范围涉及生活中的不同层面。就连十个数字也有自己的称谓。它们分别念作：1（流、朱），2（月、雷），3（汪、旺），4（则、线），5（中、乍），6（晨、龙），7（星、吉），8（张、爆），9（崖、湾）和10（足、寸）。
>   　　澳门黑社会组织的开山鼻祖是成立于十九世纪的“友谊馆”、“友乐馆”和“利卢馆”等社团。对鸦片走私和非法“苦力”贸易的插手与操纵，是澳门黑社会产生的罪恶根源。“友谊馆”相传是华籍工头林阿发等人创立。主要是为了防止华工内部纷争和外部欺侮。规定凡加入“友谊馆”将受到保护，同时将工资收入的十分之一缴交会费，否则予以解雇。不久，另一由洋人撑腰的华人工头陈光仿效“友谊馆”建立“友乐馆”。“友谊馆”和“友乐馆”各自不断扩充势力，从事各种非法活动，沦为地道的黑社会组织。至民国建立前夕，澳门相继出现了“利卢”、“同义”、“家义”、“友和”、“消义堂”、“含义”、“联英社”等黑社会组织。
>   　　北洋军阀的连年混战，日本帝国主义的入侵和国民党发动的内战，造成国内老百姓流离失所，在一定程度上为澳门黑社会的发展提供了可乘之机。至五十年代初期，澳门黑社会组织比较活跃的有“崇肇”、“友联”、“联义”、“罗梁”、“词义”、“黄馆”等，人口超过1．5万。1956年香港黑帮“双十暴动”后许多香港黑社会头面人物被递解到澳门。其中14K、水房及“和胜义”等香港黑社会成员不久便在澳门成立组织。日后经过血腥的搏杀后成为现时澳门黑社会的重要帮派。六十年代中期，澳门相继出现了一些新的堂口，例如在大三巴一带出现的“三巴堂”、新桥附近出现的“新义”等。七十年代，由于澳门经济支柱的赌业的繁荣，使得黑社会犯罪猖撅泛滥。1978年初，葡澳政府颁布《管制黑社会法》，加强对黑社会的打击。到了八十年代，澳门黑社会“过江龙”（外来）和“陀地友”（本地）不断拼杀；特别是“文革”期间来自大陆的大圈仔充当了狠角，手段残忍。据保守的统计，八十年代中期，澳门黑社会组织成员约有1．4万人。其中14K约有4千人，水房约有3千人，和胜义约有2千人。进入九十年代，前期黑社会组织活动相对平缓，从1996年下半年开始，澳门黑帮的均势被打破，黑社会势力围绕赌场利益的争夺不断。由1996年澳门黑帮“14K”、“水房”、“和胜义”和“大圈帮”组成四联公司与香港黑帮‘“和胜和”、“联公乐”等为争夺赌场利益开始，逐渐演变为近年来澳门本地两大黑帮“14K”与“水房”之间的及“14K”与吴伟势力之间的厮杀。
>   　　目前，澳门主要的黑帮有14K、水房、和胜义、大圈帮、福建帮和吴伟势力。现时“14K”势力受到沉重打击，坐馆尹国驹和一批14K人员于1998年5月被捕。1999年11月尹国驹被澳门高等法院判处15年监禁，同时被判刑的还有黄达豪、陈成良、黄蕴华、林王燕p
>   14K骨干。同月，陈月波、叶锦添、吕伟雄3名14K骨干被判监禁。14K许多骨干成员被判被抓或在逃，使得14K处于群龙无首的状态。水房是近几年黑帮争斗中最大的受益者。现任坐馆是吴X根，实权由赖X生（水房赖）控制。以吴X根为首的水房成员近1000人，主要集中于青洲、筷子基、新桥区，对澳门北区也有较大的控制权。经济来源主要是走私、搬迁、物业管理以及在赌场“叠码”，放高利贷等。以赖X生为首的水房成员约2（X人，掌握着“水房”大部分赌场利益，经营有多家公司，经济实力雄厚。“水房”与“14K”的矛盾冲突，实际上是赖X生势力与“14K”的矛盾冲突。大圈帮是澳门黑帮最好勇斗狠的帮派。1998年底，在葡澳政府的打击下，头目谭X活和骨干马X那、张X谷、陈X华等纷纷外逃。1999年5月，其行动组组长叶成坚在内地被抓。目前大圈帮人马分成三胜势力：一是原行动组骨干黄X雄（马刀）一伙投靠了“湖南帮”头目梁X（盲忠）旗下；二是在地产商吕X光赌厅从事“看场”的原谭X活手下；三是形成以谭X活胞弟谭X良为首的势力。‘’和胜义”一向和14K关系较好，在1998年反黑行动中受到较大打击，其头目江X良（石歧良）于1999年7月被澳葡法院判处6年监禁。吴伟是具有香港14K背景的澳门赌场经营人，其拥有的人马在澳门是一支不可忽视的势力，总部设在新。纪酒店。1997年8月，吴伟为了赌场利益，邀请了香港的14K、新义安、和合图及公乐等成员对付澳门14K。在
>   1998年江湖大战中，吴伟势力曾陷于空前的困境，不但在澳门被
>   14K夺去多间赌厅，而且在内地的投资也很不理想，例如在国内投资的“芙蓉花园”因资金不足而“烂尾”，在江西投资的伯爵香烟销路一般。1999年下半年后生意转好，致力扩展赌场生意。福建帮一直是很令澳门警方头痛的帮会，和台湾帮关系较好。福建帮通过开办企业，参与赌场生意，建立了一定的经济基础。在警方的打击下，福建帮近年活动趋于平静，一些活跃骨干王X勇（福建勇）、吴X林（福建林）、吴X峰（肥仔峰）等纷纷潜回内地。
>   　　澳门黑社会组织根据组织内部的紧松程度可以分为三种类型：（1）紧密型。它们大都依据洪门的组织形式创立而成，有严格等级及相关制度。是一种以犯罪为常业的具有破坏力、规模较大、存续时间较长的稳定组织。例如：14K、水房、和胜义。（2）半紧密型。指以公开、半公开或合法的体育团体等形式出现，内部有的也仿效洪门的组织结构成立的黑社会组织。例如，成立于
>   1937年的“联义”（体育会）、成立于
>   1932年的“罗梁”（体育会）、成立于1950年的“利庐”（体育会）。（3）松散型。指黑社会组织内部没有严格的组织结构，大都是以血缘或籍缘为联络纽带。例如，福建帮、湖南帮等。澳门主要的黑社会组织内部组织结构和香港三合会基本相同，也可以分为山主、副山主、红根、白纸扇、草鞋、普通会员等职级。除上述职级外，尚有“亚公”、“大哥、大佬、顶爷”之称谓。所谓“亚公”是指高一辈份的大哥，而“大哥、大佬、顶爷”是指无特别指明职务的领导人。澳门黑社会成员除了从事贩毒、走私、操纵淫业等犯罪勾当外，围绕澳门的博彩业，从事由博彩业衍生的叠码、放数、看场、收保护费等行业是其主要营生手段。此外，黑社会组织极力向警界、市政、立法机关甚至内地的政府机关渗透，寻求支持和保护，物色代言人，澳门不少有势力的人士和黑社会组织有着紧密的关系。这是澳门黑社会组织猖撅的根本因素。
>   　　四 　　港澳黑社会组织对大陆的渗透开始于八十年代初期。从渗透主体来看，香港黑社会组织是最早潜入大陆的黑帮之一。早在
>   1981年，深b；l就发现有香港的“14K”、“水房”、“和胜和”、“新义安”和“老东”等组织的成员进入该市活动。在珠海，1982年在拱北口岸发巩有澳门黑社会组织渗透活动，之后逐步扩大至香洲、湾仔、前山、南屏、唐家和斗门等地。八十年代，港澳黑社会组织对内地的渗透无论是从成员数量上，还是从渗透地域上都是小规模的，一开始基本上是组织成员的个人行为，而且成员大都是普通会员，很少有大哥级的人物入境。从渗透的区域上看，港澳黑社会由于地缘、亲缘的关系各有侧重，港澳黑社会组织大都向珠江三角洲渗透，一般香港黑社会成员主要向深圳、惠州、广州、佛山等地渗透，而澳门黑社会成员主要潜入珠海、江门、中山一带活动，台湾黑社会则主要向闽南三角地带和上海等地输出。一般是以旅游观光、探亲访友、投资办厂等名义进入内地，大都是企图建立据点发展组织，也有部分成员是直接入境进行暴力犯罪。进入九十年代，港澳黑社会基本熟悉了内地市场。开始了有计划、有组织的罪恶输出，不少黑社会组织都把内地视为“新大陆”，纷纷建立固定的据点，许多大哥级人物也忙着考察内地市场，而且被渗透区域也开始变得多元化。不断向南北发展势力，极力向内地城市渗透，海南的海口、三亚，浙江的宁波、温州，山东的青岛，辽宁的大连等沿海城市都先后成为黑社会组织渗透的重点。同时，长沙、南昌等大批内陆城市也成为其垂涎之地。
>   　　港澳黑社会对大陆的渗透具有很强的暴力性和侵财性，或勾结内地不法分子和不法势力。或自设炉灶，形成一股罪恶的地下势力，对渗透地的社会秩序，人民生命财产安全有着极大的危害。从形式上看，其涉嫌的违法和犯罪行为可归纳为以下12种：（1）看场、强索保护费；（2）走私；（3）贩毒；（4）经营赌业、地下钱庄、放债收数；（5）绑架勒索；（6）有组织的诈骗；（7）组织偷（私）渡；（8）有组织的盗窃、抢劫犯罪；（9）组织、强迫、教唆他人吸毒；（1）雇佣他人从事杀人。伤害犯罪；（
>   11）非法经营色情业、讨债业；
>   （1）为争夺地盘而进行火并等。值得注意的是港澳台黑社会组织在大陆除了从事不法勾当外，有的已在内地投资经营，并有一定的经济实力，其投资一般都是资金周转快、利润高的行业，例如，娱乐业、餐饮业、房地产业等。现仅以深8；1为例说明，目前港澳黑社会组织在该市投资的基本情况是，香港方面：（1）“新义安”头目向X波等人经营罗湖区新豪江新胜会酒吧；（2）“新义安”红根刘X参股经营罗湖区“2000”的士高；（3）“新义安”、“和胜和”成员参与经营“大富豪夜总会”；（4）“新义安”成员“赛仔雄”、“和胜和”成员周X、“14K”成员“肥仔余”等人以“灯头”方式参与经营福田区新水晶宫的士高；（5）“和胜和”头目“阿泽”等参与经营福田区CIXb的土高；（6）“新义安”成员忻X明等参与经营福田区天域的土高；（7）“14K”成员“高佬强”等参与经营福田区“哥斯拉”的士高；（8）“14K”成员陈X华经营龙岗区平湖卡拉OK；（9）“14K”成员马X川在罗湖投资经营18区卡拉OK；（1）“新义安”头目向x强在南山区开设永盛音像公司；门回）“福义兴”成员陈x在罗湖区经营海州大酒店。澳门方面：“14K”成员“老玩顺”等人以“灯头”方式参与经营福田区新水晶的士高。
>   孔萍萍

Answer (score 3):

I am talking about mainland.

We call the leader/master 大哥, which means BIG BROTHER. not 哥, not 哥哥, not 大哥哥

For the outside people, we usually call those subordinates 小哥, you see 小哥 usually charge the shops on the street for "protection". Not 小哥哥

What the boss call subordinates, I do not know, Im not Big Brother.

Answer (score 2):

老大 is for boss.

小弟 is for subordinate.

Answer (score 2):

The terms would be radically different for China or Hong Kong audience.  (But are you sure that you could obtain the approval "to stay" in the China market with triad-related contents?)